# Chart.js how define max tick of polarArea?

Tags: javascript, scale, chart.js

I look for way to use polarArea but with limit scale (line of tick) defined at 100. Actualy the scale display scale based in max value, but I want max fixed.

```
var data = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [10,20,30,40],
    }],
    labels: ["Red","Green","Yellow","Grey","Blue"]
};

var polarArea = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: data,
    type: 'polarArea',
    options: {
      scale: {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
});
```

This marked with arrow green as I want the graph.
[image: Comparison between what I want and what I have]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var data = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [10,20,30,40],
    }],
    labels: ["Red","Green","Yellow","Grey"]
};
var polarArea = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: data,
    type: 'polarArea',
    options: {
      scale: {
        ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        }
      }
    }
});
```

A JSFiddle would be super helpful for your exact situation, but based on the information provided, this should do it for you. http://jsfiddle.net/andrewborem/vup9o5fx/