# ChartJS v4 - Polar Area Chart scale

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to generate a polar area chart where the radial scale is set to 100, instead of the maximum value of the data set, in my case 80 (79). I have tried adding min, max values to the scales options and in the ticks options but nothing seems to work. I know this has varied with different versions of chart js - previous versions - you coudl do as suggested here. [Chart.js how define max tick of polarArea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432653/chart-js-how-define-max-tick-of-polararea) This no longer works.

Here is my code for the chart.

```
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'polarArea',
    data: {
      labels: ['USA', 'India', 'Australia'],
      datasets: [{
        label: '% of votes in favour',
        data: [79, 76.8, 67],
        backgroundColor: ['rgba(0,158,219,0.6)', 'rgba(219,0,82,0.6)', 'rgba(186,219,0,0.6)'],
        borderWidth: 1
      }]
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      layout: {
        padding: 0
      },
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: "bottom",
            labels: {
                // This more specific font property overrides the global property
                font: {
                    size: 16,
                    
                }
            }
        }
    },
      scales: {
        y: {
          border: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            display:false,
    
          },
          beginAtZero: true,
          grid: {
            display: false,
  
           }
        },
        x: {
          min: 0,
           max: 100,
          border: {
            display: false
          },
          ticks: {
            display:false,
     
          },
          grid: {
            display: false,
           
           }
        },
        
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You define a x and y scale why the polar area chart uses a radial scale so you will need to use `r` instead